# com.apple.developer.associated-domains issue when validating iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, app-store, appstore-approval

When I was validating my project with Organizer in Xcode, I got the following error

*Invalid code signing entitlements*. Your application *bundle's signature* contains *code signing entitlements* that are not supported on iOS.

Specifically, value `*`for key `com.apple.developer.associated-domains` in `Payload/MyApp.app/MyApp` is not supported.

I cannot find any relevant answer from google. Hope someone can help me?

Comment: Check your entitlement file and info.plist file for a start

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I had a similar problem with Xcode 5.1.1, and couldn't solve it using any of the solutions I found online. However, this worked for me:

1. Under 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles' in the Developer Member Center, choose your App ID under 'Identifiers', 'App IDs' in the left hand column.
2. Choose 'Edit' and then disable 'Associated Domains.'

[image: App Identifiers]

[image: Disable 'Associated Domains.']

Comment: Jibeex's answer would be a useful addition to this answer for those wanting to repair associated domains, instead of removing them.

Comment: After enable service of Associate Domain, is it necessary to regenerate provisioning Profile?

Answer (score 19):

Finally, I find that associated domains is only available in **Xcode6** under **Capabilities** tab. It seems that the validator is not happy if I leave this section empty. After adding an item of my domain to that section, I managed to pass the validation process..
See this link for more info about associated domains.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html

I am using Xcode 6 GM.

Thanks for the suggestion of @Sabo. I added a screenshot of my associated-domains setting. You probably need just click on the plus button and replace "example.com" with yours.

[image]

Comment: Hi , I am facing that problem too. What i need to add for associated domain. Please show with examples. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you accept your answer. This is the correct solution.

Comment: @Acey not really: if you don't need associated domains, you should remove them from the App ID on the developer portal.

Comment: This should be appended to the accepted answer. Both scenario's could be valid: requiring associated domains or removing them.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue.

Here is the resolution for anyone else having this problem.

- Log into iOS Dev Center and go to Certificates, Identifiers &
  Profiles.
- Go to Identifiers/App IDs.
- Choose the appropriate ID for your app.
- Click on the Edit button at the bottom.
- Uncheck Associated Domains and click Done.

**You will have to regenerate any provisioning files associated with this ID.**

I had never selected this for the app last time I submitted my app to the app store.

I am guessing that the update to iOS/Dev Center may have added it.

But I am not exactly sure. All I know is that I am now able to validate my package and submit to the app store.

Comment: Thanks @Vivo. It works. The important point is that, will have to regenerate any provisioning files associated with this ID.

Answer (score 5):

For me it was "***Provisioning profile "profile_name" doesn't support the Associated Domains capability***."

and I had to Enable Domain capability in iTunes Account's Profile this

Just update App ID configuration and profile and install in Xcode by double click on it.

[image]

and it worked for me

[image]

Comment: in 2021, this is no longer associated with iTunes but instead on developer.apple.com. The screenshots are still accurate though.

Answer (score 4):

Just **turn off Associated Domains** in your App ID (at developer.apple.com), and create a **new distribution provisioning profile** (if you not create profiles manually, then delete the previous at least).

It turned out to me that the value stuck into the profile even if you turn off the service. If you open the entitlements details just before you submit your app, you can see that `com.apple.developer.associated-domains` entitlement (until it is removed).

Having this, you don't need the fake entitlement entry.

Comment: In most cases you can just update the affected provisioning profiles and then refresh in Xcode.

Comment: I found I couldn't get rid of this entitlement by just turning it off. What worked to enable Associated Domains on iTunes connect and then create a fake entry in XCode under Capabilites - Associated Domains. Once I had done this, I could then turn everything off again.

Comment: @user2002649 True, if you do not recreate provisioning profile, you'll have to hack a fake entry, if you are ok with that. I just don't like that way.

Answer (score 3):

Try appending "applinks:" before your associated domain name under Associated Domains in Project Entitlement file (obviously, after enabling Associated Domains from Capabilities).

Answer (score 1):

If you're having this problem with Apple Watch, it might be that your App IDs have gotten this property automatically in the Apple Developer Portal thanks Xcode. You probably have three App IDs (one for the main app, one for the watchkitapp and one for watchkitextension).

1. Turn off Associated Domains in all three App IDs.
2. Regenerate any provisioning profiles
3. Refresh in Xcode

Ignore any instructions to go and delete your provisioning profiles manually. They refresh properly with no issues.