# Xamarin.forms iOS Install failed due to distribution provisioning issue

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I can compile my Xamarin.forms (iOS) app using manual provisioning.

Machine:
Windows
Visual Studio 16.5.5

**Certificates**
1- Apple Distribution

**Provisioning Profile**
1- App Store Distribution Profile

**Entitlements.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:example.com</string>
        <string>applinks:my.example.com</string>
        <string>applinks:hbalphaweb.example.com</string>
        <string>applinks:staging.example.com</string>
        <string>applinks:hblivemy.example.com</string>
        <string>applinks:app.example.com</string>
        <string>webcredentials:devweb1.example.com</string>
        <string>webcredentials:my.example.com</string>
        <string>webcredentials:hbalphaweb.example.com</string>
        <string>webcredentials:staging.example.com</string>
        <string>webcredentials:hblivemy.example.com</string>
        <string>webcredentials:app.example.com</string>
    </array>
  <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>production</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I can compile successfully and push it to Test Flight. The problem is that my testers can't install the App because it says that The App was not provisioned properly.

I have tried deleting temp files, cleaning and restarting VS and rebuilding but all in vain.

Can any one help me to figure it out what could be possible issue?

Comment: Have your testers added the provisioning files in their system's key chain?

Comment: Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784728/com-apple-developer-associated-domains-issue-when-validating-ios-app) since you are using Associated Domains

Comment: You could firstly update the IDE to latest version (15.6.0) and check if the problem still exists .